# Detect a pause during call in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, twilio, core-audio, phone-call

I have a requirement to detect a pause while speaking over call(It may be VOIP call) and send an pre-recorded reply automatically using Core Audio API. I explored Twilio APIs as well, I want to know feasibility of following things -

1. Is it possible to detect pause while caller from other side speaks, be it on normal call or VOIP call?
2. Is it possible to insert a prerecorded audio file during live call in iOS??

Comment: I don't believe there's any API for the phone.

Comment: For a "normal" call, you should be allowed to listen the conversation...
For a VOIP made call, you could be allowed...

Comment: @Larme Please tell how it 'should' be done for normal call and 'could' be done for VOIP call

Comment: Sorry, my bad. For a normal call, without jailbreak, you can't listen to a normal call... Security/privacy issue...
For a VOIP call, if you're the one making the VOIP session, you could be allowed to register, but only if it's your call... I mean, I don't think you could listen to the Skype.app...

Comment: I expect more specific answers

Answer (score 0):

After the introduction of [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) in iOS 10, you can detect whether the user has performed any action with DTMF which is usually the way to answer an IVR call. In case of normal human interaction it should not be possible because every call has this property of [supportsDTMF](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxcallupdate/1648585-supportsdtmf)

In a reverse scenario you can add soft and hard pauses while dialing a call programmatically as well using a simple [init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxplaydtmfcallaction/2147857-init) call.